# Writing JS tests for Django apps

Tags: javascript, django, testing, qunit

I have some django apps for which I have some templates. I have some inline JS in the template and a lot of DOM manipulations.

I would like to test the JS parts. I don't particularly want to use selenium - mostly as I don't want to run a selenium server and want to make my tests slow.

So my question is:

1. Can I write these tests with Qunit/Jasmine et all?
2. Can I integrate them with a CI?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with javascript testing is compatbility of all that fancy browser features you may use. I am not sure about the capabilities of Jasmine, but I'd take a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/), which are headless WebKit based browser automation environments.